# Possible bug with InnerPolygon and RegionUnion in version 12

Tags: regions, computational-geometry

**case1**

[image]

**case2**
[image]

**case3**
[image]

```
InnerPolygon[Polygon@Table[AngleVector[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi, 4 Pi/5}]]
InnerPolygon[Polygon@Table[AngleVector[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi, 4 Pi/5.}]]

poly = Polygon[Table[AngleVector[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi, 4 Pi/5}]]
innerPoly = InnerPolygon[poly]
{RegionUnion[poly, innerPoly], RegionUnion[poly, N@innerPoly]}

poly = Polygon[Table[AngleVector[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi, 4 Pi/7}]]
innerPoly = InnerPolygon[poly]
{RegionUnion[poly, innerPoly], RegionUnion[poly, N@innerPoly]}
```

Comment: I'd send these to support. They smell like bugs.